# How to efficiently calculate values that require the use of preceding rows?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need an efficient way to fill a calculation table that requires the preceding rows to obtain the current values.

Here is an example code showing the way I am currently doing it (slow):

```
df = data.frame(elevation = seq(1,10),
      inflow = c(3,4,6,4,3,5,6,7,8,9),
      outflow = NA,
      storage = NA)

for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  
  if (i == 1) {
    
    df$outflow[i] = 0
    df$storage[i] = 0
    
  } else {
    
    df$outflow[i] = df$inflow[i-1]/2 - df$storage[i-1] #edit 2
    df$storage[i] = df$inflow[i] - df$outflow[i] + df$storage[i-1] #edit
    
  }
  
}

df
   elevation inflow outflow storage
1          1      3     0.0     0.0
2          2      4     1.5     2.5
3          3      6    -0.5     9.0
4          4      4    -6.0    19.0
5          5      3   -17.0    39.0
6          6      5   -37.5    81.5
7          7      6   -79.0   166.5
8          8      7  -163.5   337.0
9          9      8  -333.5   678.5
10        10      9  -674.5  1362.0
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic question and learning more about how vectorization works I R would do a lot to help you understand these things better.

In your case we can take the inflow column, discard the last value, add a zero to the beginning - and we would get the values shifted by one. Then we can operate on the whole vector:

```
df$outflow <- c(0, df$inflow[-nrow(df)]/2)
df$storage <- df$inflow - df$outflow
df
   elevation inflow outflow storage
1          1      3     0.0     3.0
2          2      4     1.5     2.5
3          3      6     2.0     4.0
4          4      4     3.0     1.0
5          5      3     2.0     1.0
6          6      5     1.5     3.5
7          7      6     2.5     3.5
8          8      7     3.0     4.0
9          9      8     3.5     4.5
10        10      9     4.0     5.0
```

Based on the comment - if you want to accumulate storage - R has a special function for producing cumulative sums called `cumsum`:

```
df$outflow <- c(0, df$inflow[-nrow(df)]/2)
df$storage <- cumsum(df$inflow - df$outflow)
df
   elevation inflow outflow storage
1          1      3     0.0     3.0
2          2      4     1.5     5.5
3          3      6     2.0     9.5
4          4      4     3.0    10.5
5          5      3     2.0    11.5
6          6      5     1.5    15.0
7          7      6     2.5    18.5
8          8      7     3.0    22.5
9          9      8     3.5    27.0
10        10      9     4.0    32.0
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks. But i need an additional help.

I changed this sentence: ```df$storage[i] = df$inflow[i] - df$outflow[i] + df$storage[i-1]```. Now, how can i solve?

Comment: @BryanSouza check expanded answer.

Comment: Thank you, but what if the outflow column needs to be calculated using the value from the storage column? Please see edit 2.

Comment: Can you update the final `df` at the end too, so we can check what the result should look like? I tried to run your updated code and the numbers look weird: outflow of -600.

Comment: Done. This is just an example ```df```, dont worry.

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution

```r
library(dplyr)


df %>%
  mutate(outflow = lag(inflow, default = 0)/2,
         storage = inflow - outflow)
#>    elevation inflow outflow storage
#> 1          1      3     0.0     3.0
#> 2          2      4     1.5     2.5
#> 3          3      6     2.0     4.0
#> 4          4      4     3.0     1.0
#> 5          5      3     2.0     1.0
#> 6          6      5     1.5     3.5
#> 7          7      6     2.5     3.5
#> 8          8      7     3.0     4.0
#> 9          9      8     3.5     4.5
#> 10        10      9     4.0     5.0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>